# Using promises in sync code

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to know if is it wrong use promises in sync code.

I have a entry point file and inside i have a gigant code like:

```
Promise.resolve(MAP)
  .then((MAP) => {

    return taskOne();
  })
  .then((MAP) => {

    return taskTwo();
  })
  .then((MAP) => {

    return taskThree();
  });
```

And so on, until taskTen.

Inside each task, i have sync code, and in the final, i'm just returning the
new value of MAP, like:

```
function taskOne(MAP) {
  // DO SOMETHING

  return MAP;
}
```

I feel nice doing that, but i don't know.. Maybe i'm doing it wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: **Why** are you using promises if you only have sync code ?

Comment: I believe the maintenance is easier @DenysSéguret

Comment: I can control the flow of my application more easily. If I want to change the flow, or put some task before another it is easier. As debug .. if silent error happens, I can find it more easily.

Comment: Why is this better than `taskOne(); taskTwo(); taskThree();`?

Comment: Because i need pass MAP to each task, so i would need to reassign MAP in the entry point in each task and after call the next. Seems easier and more clear like this. Don't u?? And i can prepare my self to future async codes

Comment: Joao, You should definitely NOT abuse synchronous code in a Promises based environment. This summarizes very well why: https://medium.com/@fagnerbrack/promises-sync-code-disaster-e9d41a3c7279

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, asynchronous code is pretty much always more complicated than synchronous code so I've never seen a reason when I wanted to take something that is always synchronous and make it asynchronous.  And using promises with `.then()` forces your synchronous code to now become asynchronous.

Second off, your scheme whether written using promises or not is full of repeated code.  I'd suggest you DRY it up rather than just copy the same sequence over and over.  And while you're DRYing it up, you will probably find there's no longer a reason to use promises as you can solve your problem more succinctly in a synchronous fashion.

If all your functions take the same argument and you just want to pass along the return result of one to the next, then I'd suggest you just put the functions in an array and iterate through the array and `.reduce()` is a built-in design pattern for passing a result along from one to the next:

```
var fns = [taskOne, taskTwo, taskThree, taskFour, taskFive, taskSix, taskSeven, taskEight, taskNine, taskTen];

var final = fns.reduce(function(m, fn) {
    return fn(m);
}, MAP);
```

---

FYI, this pattern can be slightly modified to work if your functions are actually async and return promises, but I wouldn't suggest you switch to that until your functions actually are async:

```
var fns = [taskOne, taskTwo, taskThree, taskFour, taskFive, taskSix, taskSeven, taskEight, taskNine, taskTen];

fns.reduce(function(p, fn) {
    return p.then(fn);
}, Promise.resolve(MAP)).then(function(final) {
    // all done here
});
```

Comment: Lol.. Thats so much better!!!! Thanks @jfriend00!!!.. What about if in some point i add a asynchronous task??

Comment: @Joao - async version added.

Comment: A last question if u allow. You said: "And using promises with .then() forces your synchronous code to now become asynchronous." Is this a bad thing? Because if my sync code becomes async and i still can control the flow, my program shouldn't be faster??

Comment: @Joao - Nope it doesn't make it faster.  In fact, making a synchronous task async makes it slower because you're constantly waiting for the event loop to unwind rather than just executing.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/j510nsfz/ for a comparison.

Comment: Hei @jfriend00, thank you for your time! Now i get it!